how to choose only 1 file 'pdf' to download from all available files
i'm searching for a way to download multiple files from archive.org (1000s of files) only pdf document.
i went through advices on Download only 1 variant of each video file in JDownloader?
and cannot get it work. I want to download only one 'pdf' file of each file that is on the archive.org search result page i choose but jdownloader fills its menu with 5-6 all sorts of files as seen in attached jpeg, how and where can i set it up so it will download only 1 pdf file of each file availible on archive.org? i tried it all the menu on the right makes no change, set up separate rule by adding 'text.pdf' same no effect.
Jdownloader was installed and updated today, so that should work but how?
best

If this question if specific about JDownloader, I suggest you check out the JDownloader user community at https://board.jdownloader.org/. If you are open to feedback on alternative solutions, can you please edit your question accordingly?
